# Typesetting longitude or latitude followed by a comma

Tags: spacing, siunitx

How do you typeset a latitude followed by a comma? Using `siunitx` it looks like there's too much space:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
At the latitude \ang{30;30;30}, we saw a cat.
\end{document}
```

[image: Latitude]

Is there a standard way to tighten that up?

Comment: Related Question: [Should a negative kern be added after a degree symbol if followed by punctuation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115878/should-a-negative-kern-be-added-after-a-degree-symbol-if-followed-by-punctuation).

Comment: This one's 'not my fault': you'll see the same with simply `\(30''\),` as it comes down to kerning or otherwise between the glyphs.

Comment: Ah, I was't really thinking that the `siunitx` package was causing the problem, though I was kind of hoping that it had `\latitude{30}\degrees\north\by\north\west` or something ;).

Answer (score 1):

Not elegant, but:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
At the latitude \ang{30;30;30}\!, we saw a cat.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I assume the `\!` command eats some space. Where is it defined?

Comment: @bombcar Usually it is only available in math mode, but the `memoir` class defines it to be used in text as well.